The review queues are even more broken now--claiming normal items are audits
On top of the bug in review queues greying out audit items (happening for the last month or so), now the close vote review queue is suddenly telling me "this is an audit" on review items that are definitely not audits. I tried to leave a comment on this review item but was greeted with this error about audits:

This was not the first non-audit item I saw that error on today.
As you can see, going back to the review item doesn't show anything about it being an audit, and there's no indication by the score/dearth of answers that it would qualify as an audit anyway:

This issue was encountered in the close vote review queue, but given the previously-mentioned bug affects all the queues, I'm guessing this one does, too.
Can devs please fix these growing review queue bugs?

Or just remove the audit system. Whatever is easiest.

@Gimby I can't upvote comments or leave comments on review items at all so definitely more to do than removing audits :-)

This is fixed now, along with another bug where audits appear greyed out.
Kristina's answer there has a great description of the underlying cause. Basically a new feature was re-initializing an object, which set the comment functionality to "passive" i.e. read-only. This meant comments.extendCommentUi() did not exist, which caused the exception reported on that post.
For this bug specifically, that also meant comments.init() did not reset any "active" functionality, such as adding comments. When we see an audit, we overwrite some functions to show the "This is an audit" error. Previously those were reset with init() when the next task was loaded, but because of this bug, the overwrites stayed in place, so you would always see "This is an audit" on all tasks until the page was refreshed.
Very tricky one to track down! Made much easier with the details shared in these posts, so thank you!

"When we see an audit, we overwrite some functions to show the "This is an audit" error" That reads like some lovely spaghetti-code to maintain o.O

@Cerbrus No comment! :D
