Is commenting on "Review First Questions" broken?
Let me state upfront that - as far as I understand - this has nothing to do with the "Audit" questions.
I've been reviewing some first posts, and have been taking a lot of time trying to direct people to writing helpful questions, pointing them to readily available information, prompting to include missing information, etc. by adding comments. When I click "submit comment" I am immediately taken to the next First Question to review. Weird, but ok...
However, I recently discovered that if I go back and open the question in a new tab, my comment is gone. This is incredibly frustrating. The help text for first reviews states:

If appropriate, leave a detailed comment and ask for the missing information to narrow the scope of the question, or reword the question so it fits the site scope.

Is something broken or was the review system designed by a sadist? What am I missing here?

It's not just Review First Questions. It's all queues that are broken in terms of flagging, commenting, and audits: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429918/the-review-queues-are-even-more-broken-now-claiming-normal-items-are-audits#comment994363_429918 devs are busy doing... I don't know what

Thanks. I just added a comment on another review to test and it seemed to work...? I'm very disappointed to have lost 16 comments on the last 20 reviews though.

@rand'Chris - Why are you submitting a comment to a review audit? I assume by "review to test" you mean audit.  Why are you disappointed that your comments are not being submitted?  I would advise not submitting comments while performing a review.

Hi @SecurityHound, I apparently don't know what a "review audit" is. Allow me to rephrase my comment as it rejected my edit 54 minutes ago: "In order to test the commenting functionality again, I added a comment to another First Question and this time the comment was added to the post." Why does the help screen for the First Review queue explicitly suggest adding comments (as I quoted in my question) if that is discouraged?

@SecurityHound "I would advise not submitting comments while performing a review." – One of the 4 review options ("Share feedback") is solely devoted to leaving a comment. I don't think avoiding commenting in reviews is good advice, especially in this queue; providing guidance to post authors is something that's explicitly called out in the help center as something you should do for posts that might be lacking in some way that the author could fix.

@zcoop98 - Share Feedback then has you select a specific reason, only one of those options, has you write a custom comment. One should stick to the default options unless there is significant feedback to be provided (IMO).  The author performed 16 reviews and submitted 16 custom comments.  When a review is an audit you can't actually post a comment.

@zcoop98 - I could open every review the author has performed in the last couple of hours, or find a specific range of 16 reviews within a short amount of time, to determine if any of those reviews were actually audits. However, since the author is unaware of the fact we have review audits, or seem to be unaware of the term I think it's up to the author to clarify what they are referring to. I stand by my suggestion, submitting a custom comment to every review you make, in my opinion is a sign incorrect review decisions are happening.

@SecurityHound I am aware of review audits, which is why the very first line of my question states that I am not referring to those. I don't know what you are referring to when you misinterpret my comment and ignore my statement that I'm not talking about review audits. Can you clarify what it is that you are calling an review audit? And I do not post a custom comment on every review. Some 50%-ish are referrals to the help topic on how to ask questions. Some are simple "where is this function defined?". Others are more in depth. Dropping comments is very disrespectful of people's time.

@rand'Chris - You said you don’t know a review audit is…

@SecurityHound I said "apparently" because my post explicitly says I'm not talking about review audits and your comment said I was talking about review audits. What am I supposed to believe? Will you please provide your working definition of a review audit so we can all be on the same page?

A review audit, is a review when you submit your choice, indicates a pass or failure status afterwards. Additionally, if it’s a review audit, you will get a message when you attempt to submit a comment. You will also fail an audit when you choose the option to only submit a comment more than likely. This was a review audit.

I searched before asking my question. There are dozens of discussions about "review audits" like the one you linked to, and I have no idea why that is the case. My questions is absolutely and unequivocally not talking about anything like that. Thanks.

"This is incredibly frustrating" - that's something you need to work on though. It should be a minor annoyance at best. Comments disappear all the time on this site, for any number of reasons. Including bugs.

@Gimby ''This site doesn't care about your time, deal with it'' is an interesting response. It seems somewhat antithetical to the How to Ask a Good Question suggestion to "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: ..." Rules for thee but not for me?

I'm pretty confused at the apparent pushback you've received to this request; no, your comments shouldn't be disappearing, that's not supposed to happen. Comments are ephemeral, yes, but being frustrated to discover your attempts to help post authors have been thrown into the void seems completely justified (I'd be frustrated at that too!). This is clearly a bug, and as TylerH mentioned above, there are loads of other issues plaguing the queues right now (...more than usual), so this is probably related to that.

Thanks @zcoop98. I almost wish SO had a <3 flag. I've read the profiles of the people posting in this thread. The solar system appears to have orbited into a part of the galaxy dense with irony, projection, and sock puppets; an unfortunate reality these days. But after 30+ years on the internet I've had my inoculations. I just never expected it on meta.so.
